# Part of my mesh is not affected by bones

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones

*Working on Blender 2.83.3*

Download my blender project here :
[SWORD FIGHTER MODEL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0ewwNNcTkglAM8GA4E5ej7J0Cn43hFc/view?usp=sharing)

I'm trying to rig a cartoon character just for fun. I'm comfortable with most blender features but this one : Rigging.
Most of my rig is working relatively well (still figuring things out by tries and errors). However here I tried everything to no avail.

I moved the arm. As you can see it works.
[image]

**Here is my problem:**

[image: enter image description]

As you can see I made a bone rotation. **Everything moves but the eyes** (pupils and black part of the eye.)

Everything looks correctly parented, and I joined every part of my mesh together.

I tried to make some bones really close to these parts, no result.
I tried to weight paint, without any result.

Are these meshes "too thin" to be affected? Should I "stick" the eyes to the body in some way? I don't get it.

Thanks a lot for your time.
Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually weight painting my mesh solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I believe from looking that they are separate meshes, in which case you must join them with Ctrl-J and then you should be able to weight paint it, if not you could separate the eyes and parent the separated object to a bone so that it rotates as if it were attached (but this would not morph the mesh like regular bones would).

Comment: Hi Butnik thanks for your answer.

The eyes and black parts are indeed not directly joined through vertices to the body, do they have to ? However, **they are part of the same mesh (cntrl + j)**. About Your second suggestion I'm not sure to understand correctly. All I wish is them to follow along with the body when I move the bone, that's it! :-)

Comment: In that case 1 solution may be to just select all of the vertices on the eyes and then press P in edit mode and separate it into a different mesh. By which point, without moving the separate eyes, select them and shift click the armature and CTRL TAB to go into pose mode, select the bone that you want the eyes to follow and CTRL P, bone relative. This should attach the eyes.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot for your time.