# Eyes not moving with body

Tags: rigging, armature

So i have a character with just 3 bones going through the middle of his body. The eyes (separate objects from the body) also have bones as shown in the picture. The bigger middle bones control the smaller ones for moving the eyelids and the eyeball.
The only thing i don't understand is how to get the eyes to move with the body but still be able to move the eyelids and eyeball. I tried parenting the eyeball to the body but then the eye moves inside the body and still doesn't do anything in pose mode. The picture shows the character with the top eyelid on the right eyeball and the bottom eyelid on the left eyeball. It's in X-ray view.
The armature for the body and eyes are separate armatures.

What i tried so far:

- joining the eyeball and body. This stops the eyeball from moving individually though.
- Parenting the eyeball bones to the body. This moves the eyes to a really weird spot and doesn't make them move with the body. When placed back at their original spots, the eyeball bones don't function properly anymore.

[image]

[image: X ray view of the character with the bones, it shows the bottom eyelid on the left eye and the top eyelid on the right eye.]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Part of my mesh is not affected by bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187452/part-of-my-mesh-is-not-affected-by-bones)

Comment: hello please share your file, it's always easier to understand with the object itself: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots i added the blend file!

Comment: so first thing you'd better use only one armature, and maybe also one object (eyes + body), it would make things easier. Then you need to parent the main eye bone to the head bone, and parent the eye meshes to the eye bones...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a suggestion:

- Select your two eye armatures, shift select the main armature and join (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>).
- Join the eye balls to the body mesh (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>).
- In *Edit* mode, with the help of some *Cursor to Selected* and *Selection to Cursor*, put the head of the eye bone in the center of the eye. Align correctly the second eye bone (target).
- In *Edit* mode, parent the 2 eye bones to the head bone.
- Give the correct name to your bones, like *Head* for the head, *Eye_R* for the eye, *Target_R* for the target...
- Select the eye mesh, create a new vertex group called *Eye_R* and click *Assign*. As your mesh is parented to the armature, this vertex group will be automatically controlled by the bone that has the same name.
- In *Pose* mode give the eye bone a *Track To* constraint with the bone called *Target_R* as *Target*.
- This was just for one eye. As you'll probably rig the second eye, you'll create the same two bones, but you'll also have to create a new bone in front of the face, parent it to the head, parent the 2 targets to this new bone. This new bone will allow you to move the 2 targets together.

File here: [image]

### [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It now works perfectly!

Comment: as you'll probably put a second eye, you'll have to create a new bone in front of the face, parent it to the head, parent the 2 targets to this new bone, it will, allow you to move the 2 targets together, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I am going to redirect you to a similar question that I answered which I think will fix your problem, let me know if not. [Similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/187452/part-of-my-mesh-is-not-affected-by-bones/187540?noredirect=1#comment314453_187540)

Comment: I tried doing what the solution on that similar question said but it moved the eyes to a really weird spot. The eyes already have bones. These bones are separate armatures from the armature of the body. The eyeballs and eyelids just need to move with the body. I tried parenting the eye bones to the body bones but that just moves the pupil and not the whole eyeball